# WCF JSON Deserialization Issues with Whitespace

Tags: c#, wcf, json, rest, whitespace

I have a WCF REST service that accepts a custom DataContract argument as JSON which may either by the super-type or a sub-type. When I pass JSON containing extra whitespace, the object always deserializes as the super-type. When I strip all whitespace from the JSON, the object deserializaes as the sub-type.

Here is an example:

```cs
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(SubClass))]
public class SuperClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SubClass : SuperClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Extra { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke]
    void LogMessage(SuperClass arg);
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void LogMessage(SuperClass arg)
    {
        if (arg is SubClass)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SubClass");
        }
        else if (arg is SuperClass)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SuperClass");
        }
    }
}
```

If I send the following message, the service will print `SuperClass`:

```
POST http://localhost:5763/Service1.svc/LogMessage HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: text/json
Host: localhost:5763
Content-Length: 86

{    "__type":"SubClass:#WhitespaceTest",    "Message":"Message",    "Extra":"Extra" }
```

I get the same result if I "pretty print" the packet as well so that the JSOn is split over multiple lines. However, the service will print `SubClass` if I strip the whitespace as follows:

```
POST http://localhost:5763/Service1.svc/LogMessage HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: text/json
Host: localhost:5763
Content-Length: 73

{"__type":"SubClass:#WhitespaceTest","Message":"Message","Extra":"Extra"}
```

I've debugged the output of `System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()` and noticed that the XML generated from the JSON is different between the 2 packets:

```xml
<!-- First packet, deserializes to SuperClass -->
<root type="object">
    <__type type="string">SubClass:#WhitespaceTest</__type>
    <Message type="string">Message</Message>
    <Extra type="string">Extra</Extra>
</root>

<!-- Second packet, deserializes to SubClass -->
<root type="object" __type="SubClass:#WhitespaceTest">
    <Message type="string">Message</Message> 
    <Extra type="string">Extra</Extra> 
</root>
```

So, it seems as though the whitespace confuses the JSON deserializer. Does anyone know why this happens and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue which was fixed in the 4.5 framework. Unfortunately you essentially need to strip the white spaces from the front of the object if you want to use polymorphism in the current framework version. One way to do that is to read / write the JSON using a reader / writer created by `JsonReaderWriterFactory`, as it will strip the white spaces (or any pretty printing) around the elements.

```
public class StackOverflow_8661714
{
    [DataContract(Name = "SuperClass", Namespace = "WhitespaceTest")]
    [KnownType(typeof(SubClass))]
    public class SuperClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "SubClass", Namespace = "WhitespaceTest")]
    public class SubClass : SuperClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Extra { get; set; }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string originalJson = "{    \"__type\":\"SubClass:WhitespaceTest\",    \"Message\":\"Message\",    \"Extra\":\"Extra\" }";
        byte[] originalJsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalJson);
        MemoryStream writeStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlDictionaryWriter jsonWriter = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(writeStream, Encoding.UTF8, false);
        XmlDictionaryReader jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(originalJsonBytes, 0, originalJsonBytes.Length, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
        jsonWriter.WriteNode(jsonReader, true);
        jsonWriter.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(writeStream.ToArray()));
        writeStream.Position = 0;

        DataContractJsonSerializer dcjs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SuperClass), new Type[] { typeof(SubClass) });
        object o = dcjs.ReadObject(writeStream);
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a KB article from Microsoft that it was a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I have no good answer to this.  We ran into the same issue and contacted Microsoft about it.  They insisted that what they were doing was okay because of performance concerns, which is laughable considering how the entire pipeline works.

So our experience has been that whitespace in many places causes issues.  Also, if you put the __type field anywhere but the first, you'll get the supertype.

My advice would be to look at other solutions to JSON.  Unfortunately I'm not up on the alternatives or I'd suggest something.

**Edit:** As carlosfigueira points out, this has apparently been fixed in 4.5.  I have not tried it there as of yet.

Comment: As an alternative I think just about the only sensible thing to do is pass the JSON through to your service directly and then use something like [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) to deserialise the objects manually. Either that or try to work out a pre-processor that intercepts all JSON and strips any whitespace/newlines out before the message gets to the deserialiser, which will probably cause errors further down the line.